# Top 5 Folders Consuming The Most Space?

Tags: python

My hard drive is full.

What is the easiest way to find out the TOP 5 FOLDERS that consume the most disk space?

A `python` solution would be greatly appreciated. I use `Ubuntu Linux`.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Why not just download one of the many applications out there that analyze disk usage and show you the largest folders?

Comment: Are you looking for a preexisting application that does this, or are you trying to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a python solution, but one using the shell is to use `du`. To list the number of kilobytes in each folder under /var/ then sort by size with the largest one last, run the following in a shell prompt:

```
du -k --max-depth 1 /var/|sort -n
```

If you want this under python, use the always super-handy subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/du", "-k", "--max-depth", "1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, stderr) = p.communicate()
```

Split output by newline, then by tab, then sort, and you'll have the results in python.

Comment: this is very unix specific solution. this would not work on windows.

Comment: How does this handle hardlinks? I assume symlinks are ignored (as usual under linux by default?)

Comment: Eric, this is perfect -- exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Not a Python solution and not a code example: 
http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A simple and pure python solution:

```
import os

def get_folder_size(folder_path):
    folder_size = 0
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(path, file)
            folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
    return folder_size

def get_file_size(file):
    return os.path.getsize(file)

print get_folder_size("/home/magnun")
print get_file_size("/home/magnun/background.png")
```

This functions returns the size (a long type) in bytes, you may need to convert it into MBytes, GBytes and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the properties of each folder and look for the total size of the files in it. In Ubuntu, just right click on the folder, click properties and check the contents size. Not a python solution, but much easier (not everything needs a script to find the answer).  The biggest folders will likely be the ones at the top of the tree.

Comment: lol ... that's exactly what i was thinking ... but what if the top level had 400 folders? ...

Comment: Then the problem is a bit harder... most people don't have that problem though